# Can't get rid of inherited delegate method warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a class `ParentViewController` that implements a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with the target method being called `tap`. I am trying to override this method in a subclass `ChildViewController` as follows:

```
- (void) tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [super tap:sender];
}
```

It works fine, but I'm getting the warning:

```
'ChildViewController' may not respond to 'tap:'
```

In the past when I've overridden a delegate method I haven't really had any trouble like this. What am I missing here?

Comment: did you declare it in the .h for the ParentViewController ?

Comment: Nah, I kept thinking it was a delegate method but I forgot it was just a target action thing. I did that and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `-(void) tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender` is defined in ParentViewController.h